# Angular2 ng2-auto-complete implementation issues

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have implemented the Angular 2 `ng2-auto-complete` component by following this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pB1Gx?p=preview). You can access it from [here](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-auto-complete) also.

The issue I'm facing is, my source is in the form of an object with `id` as one of the fields. And by following the implementation example of the component, the `id` is displayed in parenthesis in the dropdown. Is there a way to not display the `id` in the dropdown?

Here is my HTML code for the auto-complete component:

```
<input ng2-auto-complete id="inputEvent" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" ngModel
     name="event" #event="ngModel" [source]="items" display-property-name="name" (valueChanged)="onSelect($event)"/>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `value-property-name` attribute to `null`:

```
<input ng2-auto-complete id="inputEvent" class="form-control"
[(ngModel)]="model" ngModel name="event" #event="ngModel"
[source]="items" value-property-name=null
display-property-name="name" (valueChanged)="onSelect($event)"/>
```

`value-property-name` is optional attribute, but it has default value - `id`. Setting it to `null` won't display anything, which is what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [ang2-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang2-autocomplete)
the live sample is available at : plnkr.co/edit/5zRD0fcOZHXEMOk4kupY?p=preview